# H12's when switching from Unicorn to Puma on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, puma

As recommended by Heroku, I switched one of our Rails 3.2 (/Ruby 2.0.0) apps from Unicorn to Puma. Almost immediately we started seeing many 30 second timeouts (H12 errors) on at least 5% of our requests. Something we never had when running on Unicorn.

Here's our setup:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT'] || 3443
environment ENV['RACK_ENV']     || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Valid on Rails up to 4.1 the initializer method of setting `pool` size
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] || Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Since our app is likely not thread safe, we've set `MAX_THREADS` to `1` and scaled the processes by setting `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to values ranging from `4` to `8`. We generally run a number of 2x dynos, but we also tried 1x dynos. No matter how we up- or downscale these, the H12's keep coming. Memory usage stays within the normal bounds. Additionally, since we're running just 1 thread per processes, we have set the `DB_POOL` to `1`. We have also configured Rack::Timeout to timeout at 28 seconds.

I'm stuck trying to find what is causing this. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going wrong or how to most easily find what is causing this?

Thanks!

P.S. The main reason why we want to move away from Unicorn, is because we tend to have a number of occasional slow clients that block a whole array of request transactions. Puma presumably does not suffer from this, so we would really like to get that going.

Comment: Without more performance information it's tough to tell.  I recommend adding New Relic so you can see in better detail what bottlenecks you have.    Also: "Since our app is likely not thread safe, we've set WEB_CONCURRENCY to 1 and scaled the processes by setting WEB_CONCURRENCY to values ranging from 4 to 8. " -- just an observation, but you're defining the constant `WEB_CONCURRENCY` twice.

Comment: Thanks, @Kelseydh. I corrected the typo. We have New Relic hooked up, analysed everything, but were unable to find any clue as to why these timeouts were happening. :(

Answer (score 1):

(sorry, no answer here, but hopefully this will evolve into one!)

I'm wrestling with this as well.  One thing I've determined is that for 99% of the H12’d requests, I don't have a **single** log entry from Rails itself -- just from `heroku[router]`.  (1% have log lines from the one or more of: Rack-Timeout middleware, Rails itself, or my own logging in a before_filter)

I determined this by configuring Rails to log the request-id (and incidentally, the worker's PID) with each log line, and then wrote a *quick-n-dirty* shell script to search through the log files.  (I set up my own syslogd logdrain which saves logs into a file named 'heroku')

Add to `config/application.rb`

```
## Log the X-Request-ID HTTP request header, provided by Heroku's load-balancer
## (or created by Rails itself, in its absence, e.g. on dev)
## Rails exposes this value as `request.uuid`.
## log_tags[] calls `request.send(symbol)` and adds "[value] " to the start of each logged line.
## See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id
config.log_tags = [ :uuid ]
config.log_tags << proc { "PID:#{$$}" }
```

Log parsing script:

```
cat heroku | 
    grep code=H12 | 
    perl -pe 's/^.*request_id=([^ ]*).*/$1/' | 
    while read id ; do
        echo -n "$id: "
        cat heroku |
            grep $id | 
            wc -l
    done
```

or in one line:

```
cat heroku | grep code=H12 | perl -pe 's/^.*request_id=([^ ]*).*/$1/' | while read id ; do echo -n "$id: " ; cat heroku | grep $id | wc -l ; done
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Interesting finding. Did you also have a look at the reply in the [issue I created in the Puma project on Github](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/681)? I'd be interested to know if that solves anything for you. We're still on Unicorn for now...